# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 50)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create this simpleRNN Architecture from TensorFlow
I have an input data with dimension `(8,50)` rows & colons respectively, and the output matrix (8,8).

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.regularizers import l2

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(
                        units= 8,
                        activation='sigmoid', 
                        kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0), 
                        input_dim = 8))
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3),
          loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
          metrics=[keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()],)


model.fit(
    x=trainingData,     # (8*50)
    y=OutputData,       # (8*8) 
    batch_size=5, 
    epochs=2000, 
    verbose=0,)
```

I have looked through several stackoverflow and github suggestions for a similar problem, but none works.

Could someone help me please as I don't understand why all these methods failed.

Comment: You have specified `input_dim = 8`, so it expects your last dimension as 8, but it is 50. The shape should represent `(number_of_samples, number_of_timesteps, number_of_features)` for RNN layers. With `(8,50)` you have 8 samples and each of them has 50 features. So, the `input_dim` should be equal to 50, and also you should specify timesteps dimension. I mean your input shape should be like say `(8,10,5)`.

Comment: @Kaveh, 1st of all I appreciate your effort so, Thanks a lot. but I've tried to do this before in a similar way. and the output appears.                                            
ValueError: Input 0 of layer simple_rnn_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 8, 10, 5] .                                             Is there something I haven't noticed?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705356/14290681) answer your question?